# DVD RW Drive (E:) is stuck, not opening

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

System: Win 7, 32 bit  Lenovo K-series PC
The system was not in use for some time(4-5 months)
Problem: DVD RW Drive (E:) is stuck, not opening
Info: CD/DVD driver is ok

Messages:

1. While ejecting:

   > An error occurred while ejecting 'DVD RW Drive(E:)'.
2. With chkdsk:

   > Cannot open volume for direct access

Comment: Is the disk also not ejecting using the external button ?

Comment: No. Tried that too. Also there is no hole to press the button with some pin as shown in some youtube references.

Comment: Did you try turning it off, and then on again? Or whacking it a few times? AFAIK `chkdsk` is not intended to run on optical UDF drives.

Comment: yes. I used chkdsk just to check status of of the drive.

Comment: Are you sure there's no hole? It can be hard to find the first time...

Comment: Sure. It is totally covered by button and the button works perfectly,,i.e the clicking sound of inner switch is audible.

Comment: Maybe add the actual model and/or a picture of your drive. Did you try to eject the whole unit and have a look at it outside of the device?

Comment: yeah. removed the whole unit. One wire was not connected.

Comment: does chkdsk doesn't work for DVD RW drives. because after working correctly also chkdsk e: shows "cannot open for direct access" ??

Comment: Just discovered a new problem. After removing the CPU front plate, it's working perfectly but after sticking with front plate, it stucks again.

Comment: It is opening some times and doesn't for other instances.

Comment: As it was already mentioned `chkdsk` is not meant to be used on non-FAT/FAT32/NTFS drives. It's supposed to read the content and fix or report on errors but it can't really do that for other filesystems as it's missing information. If it's not working with the plate on you might have a faulty connection somewhere else as well.